# My Opengl triangle has unexpected vertex colors

Tags: opengl, nim-lang

Hello I drawn an opengl triangle that worked fine with 3 floats color vertex attributes. The alpha one was in the shader.

Now in this version I'm trying to send color attributes with 4 floats. But the colors are wierd and the third vertex is always black.
The programming language is Nim.

```
type 
    OGLfloat = float32
    OGLuint = uint32
    OGLint = int32

# Glfw3 and Opengl constants

const
    GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR = 0x00022002
    GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR = 0x00022003
    GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE = 0x00022008
    GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE = 0x00032001

const 
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00004000
    GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00000100
    GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00000200
    GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00000400
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER = 0x8892
    GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER = 0x8893
    GL_FALSE = 0.char
    GL_STATIC_DRAW = 0x88E4
    GL_FLOAT = 0x1406
    GL_VERTEX_SHADER = 0x8B31
    GL_COMPILE_STATUS = 0x8B81
    GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH = 0x8B84
    GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER = 0x8B30
    GL_LINK_STATUS = 0x8B82
    GL_TRIANGLES = 0x0004
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT= 0x1405
    GL_VERSION = 0x1F02

# My own constants

const 
    POSITION_LENGTH = 3.OGLint
    COLOR_LENGTH = 4.OGLint

const
    WINDOW_W = 640
    WINDOW_H = 480

let
    colorDataOffset = COLOR_LENGTH * OGLint(sizeof(OGLfloat))

# I don't pasted the opengl imports here to save some space
# Opengl imports...

var 
    #I expect a black triangle but the two first vertices are blue on screen.

    vertices = @[OGLfloat(0.0), 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                         0.5, -0.5, 0,  0, 0, 0, 1,
                         -0.5, -0.5, 0,  0, 0, 0, 1] 

    indices = @[OGLuint(0), 1 , 2]


var glfwErr = glfwInit()
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
var winHandle = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H)
glfwMakeContextCurrent(winHandle)
var glewErr = glewInit()

var 
    shadID:OGLuint
    vertSrc:cstring = """
        #version 330 core
        layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;

        out vec4 vColor;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
            vColor = aColor;

        }
        """
    fragSrc:cstring = """
        #version 330 core
        out vec4 FragColor;    
        in vec4 vColor;

        void main()
        {
            FragColor = vColor;
        }

        """

proc send_src(vert:var cstring, frag:var cstring):OGLuint =
    var success:OGLint
    # vertex
    var vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, addr vert, nil)
    glCompileShader(vertexShader)
    # Check compilation errors.
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, addr success)

    if bool(success) == false:
        echo(" vertex shader compilation failed (send_src)")
    else:
        echo("vertexShader compiled (send_src)")

    # fragment
    var fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, addr frag, nil)
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader)
    # Check compilation errors.
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, addr success)

    if bool(success) == false:
        echo("fragment shader compilation failed (send_src)")
    else:
        echo("fragmentShader compiled (send_src)")

    # Shader program
    result = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(result, vertexShader)
    glAttachShader(result, fragmentShader)
    glLinkProgram(result)
    # Check for linkage errors.
    glGetProgramiv(result, GL_LINK_STATUS, addr success)
    if success == 0:
        echo("program linking failed (send_src)")
    else:
        echo("shader linked (send_src)")

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader)
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader)

glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H)
shadID = send_src(vertSrc, fragSrc)

var VAO, VBO, EBO:OGLuint
glGenVertexArrays(1, addr VAO)
glGenBuffers(1, addr VBO)
glGenBuffers(1, addr EBO)
glBindVertexArray(VAO)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.len * sizeof(OGLfloat), 
             addr vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.len * sizeof(OGLuint), 
             addr indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# Position layout
glVertexAttribPointer(0, POSITION_LENGTH, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (POSITION_LENGTH + COLOR_LENGTH) * OGLint(sizeof(OGLfloat)), 
                      nil)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
# Color layout
glVertexAttribPointer(1, COLOR_LENGTH, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (POSITION_LENGTH + COLOR_LENGTH) * OGLint(sizeof(OGLfloat)), 
                      cast[pointer](colorDataOffset))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glBindVertexArray(0)
glUseProgram(shadID)

while bool(glfwWindowShouldClose(winHandle)) == false:
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBindVertexArray(VAO)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, OGLint(indices.len), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nil)
    glfwSwapBuffers(winHandle)
    glfwPollEvents()

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, addr VAO)
glDeleteBuffers(1, addr VBO)
glDeleteBuffers(1, addr EBO)
glfwDestroyWindow(winHandle)
glfwTerminate()
```

I didn't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up the pointer for tyour color attribute, you are using:

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(1, COLOR_LENGTH, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (POSITION_LENGTH + COLOR_LENGTH) * OGLint(sizeof(OGLfloat)), 
>                   cast[pointer](colorDataOffset))
> ```

So it means that at byte offset `colorDataOffset`, you first color attribute begins.

Since your vertex format is `(3*4 bytes position | 4*4 bytes color)`, the correct offset would be 12, so to skip the position part of the very first vertex. However, you set it to:

> ```
> colorDataOffset = COLOR_LENGTH * OGLint(sizeof(OGLfloat))
> ```

which should evaluate to 16, so you actually mix it with the position data of the next vertex.

You need to use `POSITION_LENGTH` here...

Comment: Thank you, it's so easy to create unexpected results in that opengl stuff !